# Setting the elements of a list equal to elements of a different list

Tags: code-request

```
A = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}
B = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

How would I go about setting some of the elements in list A equal to the elements in list B and then the left over elements in list A will be set to 0.  For example, set a=1, c=2, d=3, g=4, h=5 and then the leftover elements in list A are b,e,f=0.  So the new list A would be

```
A = {1,0,2,3,0,0,4,5}
```

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify what your input should be so I have to guess.  Perhaps:

```
A = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};
B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
pos = {1, 3, 4, 7, 8};

A[[All]] = 0;
A[[pos]] = B;

A
```

> ```
> {1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}
> ```

You could also start with this for a bit more efficiency:

```
A = ConstantArray[0, Length @ A]
```

Comment: I think that does not answer the right question: the OP wants to assign values to the symbols appearing in `A`.

Comment: @IgorRivin my interpretation is that he was merely using that notation to describe the replacements.  If not you win. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
 const = ConstantArray[0, Length[A]]
 const[[pos]] = B
 MapThread[Set, {A, const}]
```

Comment: Why a downvote?

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted, but I would guess it's because `C` is Protected, and `C[pos]` should have been `C[[pos]]`. Also `Set` by itself is cleaner than `Set[#1, #2]&`

Comment: I too did not down-vote, but additionally this is making assignments to the symbols in the list `A`, which is unlike other interpretations.  If that's actually what the OP wants then great. :-)

Comment: @SimonWoods Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
A = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};
B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
pos = {1, 3, 4, 7, 8};

aA = SparseArray[pos -> B];
aA // Normal
(* {1,0,2,3,0,0,4,5} *)
```

More generally,

```
(* replace positions # of #3 with #2 and the rest with #4 *)
foo = SparseArray[# -> #2, Length @ #3, #4]& 
foo[pos, B, A, 0] //Normal
(* {1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5} *)
foo[pos, B, A, 100] // Normal (* use 100 instead of 0 as the default element *)
(* {1, 100, 2, 3, 100, 100, 4, 5} *)
foo[{2, 3, 4, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, A, 100] // Normal (* replace any part of A *)
(* {100, 1, 2, 3, 100, 100, 4, 100} *)
```

Update: Few more alternatives:

```
ReplacePart[0 A, Thread[pos -> B]]
(* {1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5} *)
Block[{i = 1}, MapAt[B[[i++]] &, 0 A, List /@ pos]]
(* {1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5} *)
```

Comment: As written this is very clean, but if the default element is not `0`, and if you are not replacing the last element in `A`, you will need additional parameters, e.g. `SparseArray[pos -> B, Length @ A, bg]` where `bg` is the default.  +1 but I suggest you include these caveats in the answer.

Comment: @Mr.W, good point; thank you. Updated with your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
A = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};
B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
p = {1, 3, 4, 7, 8};
```

Then:

```
(A = ConstantArray[0, Length @ A]; 
 Scan[(A[[p[[#]]]] = B[[#]]) &, Range @ Length @ pos]; A)
```

> ```
> {1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
A = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};
B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Replace[A, {a -> 2, b -> 5, _ -> 0}, 1]

(* {2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} ;
{a, c, d, g, h} = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Replace[A, _Symbol :> 0, {-1}]
(*{1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5}*)
```